When mouseover on a table cell I want add a border to the cell to highlight it. But when I do this all the other cells width and height are effected
I have following html code for a simple intro page. On mousever (hover) event I will add a border to highlicght the cell. But when I do it with my existing code and css, all the cell heights and widths are increasing.How can I prevent that? I have even tried to decrease the height and widht of the cell when hover, but the result was the same. I


.td_index_intro_1 {
max-width :500px;
max-height:300px;  
}
.td_index_intro_2 {
max-width: 500px;
max-height: 300px;
}
.td_index_intro_3 {
max-width: 500px;
max-height: 300px;
}
.td_index_intro_4 {
max-width: 500px;
max-height: 300px;
}

.td_index_intro_1:hover {
border: 4px solid darkblue;
max-width: 492px;
max-height: 292px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.td_index_intro_2:hover {
border: 4px solid darkblue;
max-width: 492px;
max-height: 292px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.td_index_intro_3:hover {
border: 4px solid darkblue;
max-width: 492px;
max-height: 292px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.td_index_intro_4:hover {
border: 4px solid darkblue;
max-width: 492px;
max-height: 292px;
cursor: pointer;
}
<table class="table_intro" style="margin-left:200px; margin-top:50px;border-spacing:20px">   

<tr >
    <td class="td_index_intro_1">
        <img src="images/index_machovw.png" style="display:block;width:100%; height:100%">
    </td>
    <td class="td_index_intro_2">
        <img src="images/index_connect.png" style="display:block; width:100% ; height:100% ">
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="td_index_intro_3">
        <img src="images/index_docu.png" style="display:block; width:100% ; height:100%">
    </td>
    <td class="td_index_intro_4">
        <img src="images/index_admin.png" style="display:block; width:100% ; height:100%">
    </td>
   
</tr>
</table>




You can change border to outline:


td {
  max-width :500px;
  max-height:300px;  
}

td:hover {
  outline: 4px solid darkblue;
  max-width: 492px;
  max-height: 292px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<table class="table_intro" style="margin-left:200px; margin-top:50px;border-spacing:20px">   
<tr >
<td class="td_index_intro_1">
    <img src="images/index_machovw.png" style="display:block;width:100%; height:100%">
</td>
<td class="td_index_intro_2">
    <img src="images/index_connect.png" style="display:block; width:100% ; height:100% ">
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td_index_intro_3">
    <img src="images/index_docu.png" style="display:block; width:100% ; height:100%">
</td>
<td class="td_index_intro_4">
    <img src="images/index_admin.png" style="display:block; width:100% ; height:100%">
</td>
   
</tr>
</table>




Yes that worked great. Nice to learn something simple and new :-)
